# Concurrent Mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In One of my application i need to enter students details in `student` table. table is

```
 ID    |  NAME    | CODE 
---------------------------
 1        JOHN       A1
 2        RAM        A2
 3        ABC        A3
----------------------------
```

In this table `id` filed is an auto increment filed, and code is `maximum(code)+1`. So while saving. initially i will take the code first and then insert data into `student` table.

My problem is that, this entry doing multiple users from multiple location. sometime concurrent hit will happening. at that time same `code` coming for different students. Is there any way to solve this issue ? . Application developed using php & Mysql

Comment: Don't expect the autoincrement field to give you consecutive numbers and use the current id to generate code and you're fine. Does code absolutely need to be consecutive?

Comment: I am not expecting consecutive numbers from auto increment. i have generated code like this  `SELECT concat ('A',ifnull(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(CODE,2) AS SIGNED)),0)+1) as code FROM student  `

Comment: If not absolutely neccesary for code to be consecutive then I would use current ID to generate code. If absolutely neccessary it will be more complicated. I would probably create a different 'staging' table and periodically transfer items from the staging to main table, that way the staging allows concurrent updates but you can ensure consecutive updates to the main table..

Comment: I need consecutive codes, also i want to show that code to user after saving

Comment: You are looking for and AUTO_INCREMENT column, so that you do not do the ID+1, but the database does it for you instead.